# what is mysql query to print 1 to 10?

Tags: mysql

I know there is sql query to print count from 1 to 10 as below:

```
select rownum from dual where rownum<=10;
```

In the same way i am trying in the mysql but it is throwing error "Unknown column rownum in field list". So, It would be great if anyone provide me the mysql query to perform the same operation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to print 1 to 10 or want to print count ? If you want to fetch the count then simply change the query to select count(*) from dual where rownum<=10;

Comment: "Unknown column rownum in field list" means your Dual table do not have the rownum column

Comment: @Pragna i want to print 1 to 10 in mysql.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry I am using mysql-installer-community-8.0.1

Answer (score 6):

In MySQL 8+ you can use a recursive CTE to do this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT n FROM cte
```

Output:

```
n
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24c5657fe7ad0ff83ebee7193c95ef5e)

Answer (score 0):

[There is no straightforward way to do this in MySQL.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql)

MySQL does not fully support the `DUAL` table. It can be used as a placeholder table in certain queries which do not require a table, but it does not have the same behavior as the `DUAL` table in other database servers -- it will only ever return one row, even if more rows are requested:

```
mysql> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() FROM DUAL LIMIT 10;
+---------------------+
| row_number() over() |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() FROM DUAL WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER() < 10;
ERROR 3593 (HY000): You cannot use the window function 'row_number' in this context.'
```

(Yes, there's really a stray apostrophe at the end of that error message.)

There is one really dumb way of creating a sequence:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
+---+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously, this gets unwieldy for large sequences, but it's about the best you'll get in stock MySQL. (Some of the forks, like MariaDB, have some features which can be used for this.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the table function (the method for creating a temporary table only for the current query): like numbers function which will print 1 to 10:
`SELECT * FROM numbers(1, 10);`

Answer (score -2):

By using below query you can get 1 to 10.

**Sequence of 10 numbers**

```
select * from (select 1 x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) A
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f8b71c1fef4b8e0350f2b28eb15c3be